# Flask-SqlAlchemy or SqlAlchemy filter by

Tags: python, html, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am querying a db model using user form input. My relevant HTML form input syntax is as follows:

```
<label>Make</label>
 <select name="Car_Make" id="Car_Make_Selector" class="form-control">
   <option value="" >Any</option>
   <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
```

The sqlAlchemy query is as follows:

```
Searched_Cars = Cars.query.filter_by(Car_Make=request.args.get('Car_Make')).order_by(Cars.Date_Created.desc())
```

Now, when in the form I select a value for Car_Make="Toyota", the query works fine. But when I select the option "Any" in the form, the query results in nothing.

What I want is that, when the user selects "Any" the query shall return all cars in db. That is essentially removing the filter_by clause from the query if 'Any' is selected.

Furthermore, given I have 7 criteria to search on like colour, model and year etc and anyone or more of these criteria can be selected as "Any" by the user. So, is the following query syntax alright for multiple search criteria?

```
Searched_Cars = Cars.query.filter_by(Car_Make=request.args.get('Car_Make'),Car_Model=request.args.get('Car_Model'),Car_Colour=request.args.get('Car_Colour')).order_by(Cars.Date_Created.desc())
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by keyword arguments passed to filter_by function
You need to add only those values to keyword argument those are having value other than 'Any'

Below is sample code with that you can achieve it case - when the user selects "Any" the query shall return all cars in db

```
filter_arguments = {}
if request.args.get('Car_Make'):
    filter_arguments.update(Car_Make=request.args.get('Car_Make'))
Searched_Cars = Cars.query.filter_by(**filter_arguments).order_by(Cars.Date_Created.desc())
```

so above code will add only those filter criteria for which there is some value

similarly you can do for other filter criteria

but note to handle all filter criteria you need run query without filter_by like below

```
filter_arguments = {}
if request.args.get('Car_Make'):
    filter_arguments.update(Car_Make=request.args.get('Car_Make'))
if filter_arguments:
    Searched_Cars = Cars.query.filter_by(**filter_arguments).order_by(Cars.Date_Created.desc())
else:
   Searched_Cars = Cars.query.order_by(Cars.Date_Created.desc())
```

Comment: Thanks PythonUser. But for the above to work, I will have to add multiple if else statements given I will be filtering  on 7 different criteria like Colour, milegae etc?

Comment: yes...another way you can achieve by creating generic function which will return you the dictionary with key and values which is having some value